# Fixed size bucket hashing with consistent assignment

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am looking for a hashing algorithm satisfying the following properties, but I am not sure if it is even possible to have one like that.

I have a set of objects whose number can grow or shrink over time. I want to assign them to a set of buckets. There is a maximum limit on the number of objects per bucket. The number of buckets can increase over time as we add more objects, obviously. But once an object is assigned to a bucket, it should never get rehashed to another bucket.

Is there an algorithm that can achieve this? Is it even possible to have such an algorithm?

Comment: No, if the number of buckets can shrink, the items in the vanishing buckets **need** to be relocated.

Comment: Number of objects can shrink because some objects can get deleted, but number of buckets need not shrink. It is OK to delete a bucket if all the objects in that bucket are deleted. But I am fine with leaving an empty bucket as it is, if that helps in coming up with an algorithm.